# Google Closure Templates vs JSP performances

Tags: java, performance, jsp, google-closure

Recently I am playing with [Google soy](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_java) templates. I wonder if anyone has measured the performances of just using soys as templates (in the same way jsp or freemarker is used).

- Are the soy templates in any way faster then e.g. from JSP? I am interested in real-life usage of soy, like one where you also pass many parameters to soy context needed for the template.
- Can we see somehow the generated java classes for soy templates?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: JSPs are actually compiled to Java classes and after their first use (or if they are precompiled during build time), they are fragging fast. Everything which needs to be recompiled to a complete template and then needs to be run through some sort of DOM parser is by nature slower. But: in 99.999% of the use cases it is not the view technology which delays and needs to be performance tuned. If you like soy templates (which I don't, I even hate the hipster terminology): use them. JSP? Well, you better don't ;)

Comment: Thanx. Soy templates should be compiled, too. I just don't like the java output of JSPs, there are like thousands of line that just write simple strings to the output streams. I know that overall performance gain would not be drastically changed, but still - if I can save some cycles, lets do that :) Btw, which template engine would you use? Soy seems interesting because of language-agnostic (sort of) compilation, to javascript and java; which can be further used to optimize web pages.

Comment: Reducing complexity is far more important than "saving come cycles" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Comment: @lilalinux no doubt. still, implementation may vary. i've seen some bad examples in templating that were ridiculously slow.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason to use Soy is to allow you to easily render either Server side or client side using the same templates.  You don't have that flexibility with JSPs.
Also Soy has good support for proper escaping based on context, which results in a more secure site

Comment: Sure. But is there a `price` to pay for this?